# Windows 10 Blocking Outbound Port 443

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have a weird problem on a couple of machines.  3rd Party programs, including chrome and microsoft teams are unable to make an outbound HTTPS connection.

The error from chrome is ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED.

I've disabled antivirus, windows firewall, performed `netsh winsock reset` and even performed a PC Reset.  I cannot figure out what is causing winsock to deny the request.

Stupid thing is Edge and Internet explorer both work.  HTTP works in chrome as does HTTPS if I am using a proxy server.  Something is explicitly preventing creating outbound connections on port 443

Can anyone shed any light on how to figure out what is causing this?

The machine is Azure AD Joined, logging in as me an a few seconds after logging in the problem occurs.  If I log in as another user everything is fine - I cannot figure out what is doing it and how to detect it.

Comment: OK this now gets weirder.  Logging into the computer as another user magically fixes the issue. Switching back to the first login and it all works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was Intune Application Protection Policies getting in the way.  You need the extra Cloud Resource with a value of `/*AppCompat*/` to allow personal apps to use HTTPS on the device without a proxy server.

Annoying thing was that these rules were still blocking even thought I'd stopped the firewall!